# Logicapps connector missing

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Trying to send files from Azure file storage and did not find the stored procedure connector in logicapp workflow

[image]

Azure stored procedure connector in logicapps

Comment: Sorry but what does that have to do with Azure storage?

Comment: @Skin . Sorry Edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Azure stored procedure connector in logicapps
```

Refer this link for [Stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-long-running-stored-procedures-sql-connector)

```
Trying to send files to Azure file storage and did not find the stored procedure connector in logicapp workflow
```

If you want to send files to azure file storage, then you need to search for Azure file storage connector not for Stored procedure.
As Shown in below image if you search for Stored procedure you can see below connectors.
[image]

May be if you want to send it from file storage to SQL server you can choose Sql Server connector there you can see Execute Stored procedure action as shown below.
[image]

If in case, you want to send files to Azure File Storage then search for that connector and you can choose actions regarding your requirement as shown in below image
[image]